# How to emulate a gyroscope in an Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, gyroscope

I am trying to work on stuff related to a gyroscope. My phone does not have a built in
gyroscope. Is there a way to include the gyroscope functionality in the emulator, at least make the emulator set in such a way that it behaves as if it had a real gyroscope?

p.s. I do not need to read any values from the gyroscope, I just want the emulator to think that it has one.

I have searched thoroughly and all I've found was this: http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator

But this does not make the emulator feel that it has a in built gyroscope, instead it runs an app in the emulator and fetches readings from sensors that are simulated in "SensorSimulator".

Any info would be helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Gyroscope tutorial or sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593037/android-gyroscope-tutorial-or-sample-code)

Comment: @AndroSelva: can't see the duplication here, it's all about emulation, not about using the API which is discussed there.

Comment: @AndroSelva: No, I actually dont want the code, I have coded stuff to detect a gyroscope on an android device, but I am unable to test it as my phone does not have a gyroscope in it, hence I am looking for solution for the above query.

Comment: I have the same need. So, Does emulator support gyroscope ?

Comment: Have you tried [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/features/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gyroscope is newly supported in the Emulator of Android Studio 3.0, [released to the Canary Channel](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html) on 5/17/17.  Note that (as of today) Android Studio 2.3.3 is the latest official (i.e. "stable") version.  [Here is how you setup the Preview Version](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html) of Android Studio, which can exist concurrently with the official version.
Note that running the emulator out of the box won't work, as it's not a recent enough version:
[image]

You need to follow the 'change your update channel' steps in the latter link: select **File > Other Settings > Default Settings** and update from the Canary Channel:
[image]
Note that while running a Virtual Device with Android 7+ (aka API 26) *did* show Gyroscope output in the emulator's Virtual Sensors (within Extended Controls), it does not (at least yet) send that output to the virtual device; to actually see the environment in the sample app move as I moved the phone, I had to use Android 7.1.1 (API 25).

*(Thanks to @jamal-eason for the protip!)*

**PREVIOUS (6/12/17):**

As of the date of writing the ***release version*** of the Android Emulator (in Android Studio 2.3.3) does *not* offer Gyroscope support.

While the documentation referenced by @Nesski suggests this, I offer the following as proof:

The Android SDK's [Virtual Reality getting started demo](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/get-started) is the game called *Treasure Hunt*.  [Here is what it looks like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7l-2qpix7c) when played on a phone.  Notice that the camera moves as the player looks around.

Of the [handful of devices](https://vr.google.com/daydream/smartphonevr/phones/) compatible with the Google Daydream - because they contain an internal Gyroscope - Android Studio's AVD Manager offers only two of them: the Pixel and Pixel XL.  I downloaded two virtual devices for each of those phones so that I could run the latest two Android versions (7.1.1 and 8.0) on each device:

[image: The Virtual Devices I tested in the Emulator]

I ran each device in the Emulator, and got similar results: press <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + C</kbd> (on Windows) to bring up the [Extended Controls](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#tasks), and you'll be able to test the phone's Virtual Sensors:

[image]

Using its Rotate controls, you'll notice that while there is Accelerometer output, Magnetometer output, and Rotation output, *there is no Gryroscope output*.  **You can rotate the phone as if you were looking around, but the game's camera view does not change as the phone is moved.**

While this sad reality is unfortunate, I do, however, hope and expect Android to add Gyroscope support to the emulator in the future as more developers jump on the Google Daydream Virtual Reality bandwagon.

Comment: You need to run Android Emulator v26.1.0 (which is currently in the canary channel  ) to see the Gyroscope feature.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

The Android Emulator, launched with [Android Studio 3.0](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-studio-3-0-canary1.html) can simulate a range of rotation sensors that just might address your use case. We specially added a [Gyroscope](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+log/emu-master-dev/android/android-emu/android/hw-sensors.h) in the Android Emulator v26.1.0.

Comment: I have tested the featured. Look at the screen shot and check out the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+log/emu-master-dev/android/android-emu/android/hw-sensors.h

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any Gyroscope support in the Emulator.

[source.android.com's Sensors docs](https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/sensor-types.html#gyroscope) states

> The gyroscope cannot be emulated based on magnetometers and
>   accelerometers, as this would cause it to have reduced local
>   consistency and responsiveness. It must be based on a usual gyroscope
>   chip.

I am working on something similar so I'm kind of reading up on what data to collect and what not to.