# How to find android device orientation?

Tags: android, orientation, android-sensors, gyroscope

Is it possible to detect current orientation of an android device using sensors like Gyroscope?
By orientation I mean whether the device is held vertical to ground or placed horizontally on a surface etc...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The current configuration, as used to determine which resources to retrieve etc, as available from the Resources' Configuration object as:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

[Check this link too](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation)

Comment: I'm not looking for screen orientation, but device's orientation axis X,Y and Z

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

It will returns current activity orientation

For more information click [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380989/how-do-i-get-the-current-orientation-activityinfo-screen-orientation-of-an-a)

Comment: I'm not looking for screen orientation, but device's orientation axis X,Y and Z.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use Sensor's data to analyse the position of a device.

Please refer to the standard documentation on how to use gyroscope: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

Also, a possible duplicate of:

- [Android Gyroscope examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774496/android-gyroscope-examples)
- [Android Gyroscope tutorial or sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593037/android-gyroscope-tutorial-or-sample-code)

Comment: I'm not looking for screen orientation, but device's orientation axis X,Y and Z

Comment: @sreejith.virgo and I gave you?

Comment: I mean I had already gone through the documentation and try searching, but it only provide me ways to find the change in position. But not the position at a moment.

Comment: @sreejith.virgo you have to use the event listener anyway, sadly that is the recommended and only way. Register listener, wait for data, remove listener. No, there is no Sensor.getValue method

Comment: Ya, I found the same in documentation.But that wouldn't do what I exactly want.
Anyway thanks for your time n comments :)